# Add class to multiple divs jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I've this code :

```
$('.page-id-41').addClass('no-menu');
$('.page-id-344').addClass('no-menu');
$('.home').addClass('no-menu');
$('.page-id-444').addClass('no-menu');
$('.single').addClass('no-menu');
```

Instead of having all these lines, I want to have a single line.

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify any number of selectors to combine into a single result. This is more efficient than finding and applying it individually.

You can do with 1 line.

```
$('.page-id-41, .page-id-344, .home , .page-id-444, .single').addClass('no-menu');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like following.

```
$('.page-id-41, .page-id-344, .home, .page-id-444, .single').addClass('no-menu');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("selector1, selector2, ... selectorx").addClass("classname");
```

Group multiple selectors with a comma